# How do I perform XOR of const char in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, udp, hex

I need to send hexadecimal values to a device through UDP/IP protocol, before i need to send i have to do XOR of the first two bytes with the two bytes of the "message sequence number" problem is that

1. when and where do i find MSB and LSB of the message sequence number
2. how do i perform XOR for the first two bytes, if i do so then how to append back to the original?

here is my array const char connectByteArray[] = {0x21,0x01,0x01,0x00,0xC0,0x50};

The  below point will help to answer you better i think so
"XOR the first byte of the encryption block with the MSB of the message sequence number, and XOR the second byte of the encryption block with the LSB of the message sequence number"

Answer (score 2):

```
//Bitwise XOR operator is ^ .

 byte msb = (byte) (connectByteArray[0])<<8 //LSB
 byte lsb = (byte) (connectByteArray[0]) >> 8 //MSB
```

Comment: I don't think that works - where is the message sequence number?  You have lsb and msb back-to-front.  You are using the same byte of the `connectByteArray`.

Comment: for each array index carry this out

Comment: Where is the message sequence number?

Comment: whatever is the sequence number, it is a byte, use the  ^ operator between two message sequence numbers or whatever, if it is a byte, you will get XOR operation done. and array index of 0 is for demo, use a loop and do this for all indices

Comment: The main complexity of the question is getting hold of the UDP message sequence number in the first place.  Do you know how to do that?  XORing bytes is child's play.

Comment: Agreed - you haven't answered point 1 though have you.  You are assigning msb from the message content, not the message sequence number.

Comment: Thanks guys, but it still confusing me should i need to increment message sequence number all the time sending UdP packets to the server??